# Bigarray.Array1.t type constructor

Tags: ocaml

I saw such a type declartion at [here](https://github.com/nikola-spasojevic/AFP_part3/blob/master/part1.ml#L2)

```
type int64_array =
  (int64, Bigarray.int32_elt, Bigarray.c_layout) Bigarray.Array1.t
```

From the manual, I learnt that for `('a, 'b, 'c) Bigarray.Array1.t`, `'a` is for type of array element, and `'b` is the representation kind.

Why we can use `int32_elt` to represent `int64`?

Answer (score 1):

If the type were usable, it would say to represent values as int64 when accessed from OCaml, but to store them internally as int32 values. This is similar to the case where you store 8-bit values in the array and represent them by ints when accessed from OCaml.

However, as far as I can see you can't create any arrays of the type. You can only create arrays of kinds that are defined in `Bigarray`:

```
val float32 : (float, float32_elt) kind
val float64 : (float, float64_elt) kind
val complex32 : (Complex.t, complex32_elt) kind
val complex64 : (Complex.t, complex64_elt) kind
val int8_signed : (int, int8_signed_elt) kind
val int8_unsigned : (int, int8_unsigned_elt) kind
val int16_signed : (int, int16_signed_elt) kind
val int16_unsigned : (int, int16_unsigned_elt) kind
val int : (int, int_elt) kind
val int32 : (int32, int32_elt) kind
val int64 : (int64, int64_elt) kind
val nativeint : (nativeint, nativeint_elt) kind
val char : (char, int8_unsigned_elt) kind
```

I don't know what's going on the the code you link to. Perhaps they are doing something clever.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually from an [exercise](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1415/L28/assessment.html) (question 1 of the exercise 3) and just to clarify, this homework is already due and I am not a student of this course.